# Unable to resolve resource bundle "*" for locale "en_US" (Flex, Flash Builder)

Tags: apache-flex, skinning, flash-builder

since I'm using custom skin classes in Flex I'm getting an error, when trying to open the design view in Flash Builder:

```
Description Resource Path Location Type

Unable to resolve resource bundle "components" for locale "en_US". 
Unable to resolve resource bundle "core" for locale "en_US". 
Unable to resolve resource bundle "effects" for locale "en_US". 
Unable to resolve resource bundle "layout" for locale "en_US". 
Unable to resolve resource bundle "skins" for locale "en_US". 
Unable to resolve resource bundle "styles" for locale "en_US".
```

I tried a lot with setting locales in compiler arguments - but I thinks this error is directly related to a locale problem. When I check the flex framework directories `"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4\sdks\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark"` - here are the original skin classes located - I can see all the "missing" folders.

Anybody has a clue about that issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I could solve my problem by adding following Library Path to the Project settings / Flex Build Path:

```
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4\sdks\4.0.0\frameworks\locale\en_US
```

It seems that the Flex compiler knows the path when working with the standard skins but somehow it can't find it when dealing with custom skins.

Answer (score 1):

If any issue like this type, means it can not found your file path

Go to Project --> Property-->Flex Build Path-->Source path-->Add Folder --> locale\en_US

which file error show on Description

here is additional source folder can be add outside of the main source folder

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the previous answers here already address, there is another possible cause.

This error appears also when a required **locale is missing from the SDK** itself. The list of existing SDK locales can be found at `SDK.INSTALL.DIR/sdks/VERSION.NO/frameworks/locale`. If a required locale is not there, then you need to create it with the `copylocale` command.

For more information, see [Creating a new locale for i18N capable application](http://tamanmohamed.blogspot.com/2011/04/flex-41-creating-new-locale-for-i18n.html).

Answer (score 0):

With complete knowledge that Flex is dead, posting an answer that worked for me, for guys who have the misfortune of working on Flex to support old project like me:
I had this issue for datamanagement resource bundle.
Navigate to the path inside your sdk : "*\frameworks\locale\en_US" > Add the *_rb.swc file inside this folder.
Clean build

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the problem in Flash Builder 4.5 and resolved it as follows.
1. In the .flexConfig.xml file I have commented the unneeded locales -

```
<locale>
    <!--
    <locale-element>en_GB</locale-element>
    <locale-element>pt_BR</locale-element>
    -->
    <locale-element>en_US</locale-element>
</locale>
```

Make sure that in the "Flex Build Path\Source path" you have the following entry - "src\main\locales{locale}".

Then no need to add "locale" option in the Flex Compiler arguments.

Thanks