# Adding Base64Decoder causes build to fail

Tags: actionscript-3, air, base64

I'm encoding and decoding a binary string. It's an Adobe Air app I'm writing. 
I've imported `mx.utils.Base64Decoder;` and `mx.utils.Base64Encoder;` I've included tons of libraries and I've even gone to this link http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/trunk/frameworks/projects/framework/src/mx/utils/ and downloaded the `Base64Decoder.as` and included it as a library. I'm including the `framework.swc` as a library too, and I'm able to use `Base64Encoder` just fine. But as **soon** as I uncomment the line

```
var dec:Base64Decoder = new Base64Decoder();
```

I cannot build the project. It will tell me that the project has errors and cannot build. 
does anyone have any clue what could be happening here? I'm so frustrated with this.

Comment: Are you trying to access `dec` after that line? That line includes the declaration, so if you don't also comment out the other lines, there are errors within the project as you are trying to access an undefined property. If that isn't the case, could you please provide the full error statement?

Comment: Yes I've commented out everything except this line. I actually found that I'm getting the error `Unable to resolve resource bundle 'utils'` I can trace it back to the declaration in Base64Decoder at line 19. `[ResourceBundle("utils")]`, but I can't figure out what do do about it. No it's not any of these issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108065/unable-to-resolve-resource-bundle-for-locale-en-us-flex-flash-builder, http://forums.adobe.com/message/4242816, etc...